# lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags

Tags: linux

For one of our Linux servers running CentOS 6.0, if I do lsattr /home, I get something like this (as root):

```
$lsattr /home
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/user
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/user
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /home/DIR
```

Now, I try to change something with chattr

```
$chattr -R -i /home
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /home
```

Mount returns:

```
$mount
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
```

I have no clue how to fix this. Could somebody help?

Comment: Could you please post the output of `cat /proc/mounts`?

Comment: That was it. I had used automount to mount home directories for LDAP logins in /home/DIR and had removed it later- but it was still mounting /home/DIR as automount. That fixed it. Anyway, why would mount not return automount mount points?

Answer (score 14):

The filesystem where `/home` is located has to support [Extended Attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). Since `/home` is most likely located on your `LogVol00` partition (and not an NFS mount or something), you have to mount the filesystem with the `user_xattr` mount option:

> mount -o remount,user_xattr /

Note that for `ext4` both `user_xattr` and `acl` are [enabled by default](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/3/24/656). This varies for other filesystems.

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is an old thread, but it looks likely the directories under /home are automounted nfs exports and nfs does not support chattr, lsattr etc.. You would have to set this on the nfs server's filesystem (if possible) to make the files immutable.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to presume that /home is under your root volume.  What you have to do is to change your /etc/fstab file for the root volume to add the 'acl' option.  This activates ACLs on the filesystem.

To then activate ACLs either remount the root volume (mount -o remount,acl /) , or reboot the system (as the acl option is now in the options field for the root volume).

Comment: Thanks. I tried your approach but I get the same error message.

Comment: While somewhat related, [ACLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) are not to be confused with extended attributes.